# How do I preserve hierarchical tables with pandas pivot_table and dataframe styles?

Tags: python, html, pandas, pivot-table

In pandas version 18.1,  I can't figure out how to use the .style element on a pivot table to render the result hierarchically, as is done in the default
`to_html` function.

Is there some option that preserves the hierarchy of multi-indexes in dataframes when rendering output using the stylers?

See the visual differences between the two tables below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(0)
a = np.random.randint(1, 4, 10)
b = np.random.randint(1, 4, 10)
c = np.random.randint(5, 9, 10)

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(A=a,B=b,C=c,Val=np.random.randint(1,10,10)))

tbl=pd.pivot_table(df,index=['A','B','C'], aggfunc=sum)
print tbl.to_html()
print tbl.style.render()
```

Produces:

```html
<table border="1" class="dataframe">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: right;">
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th>Val</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>A</th>
      <th>B</th>
      <th>C</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th rowspan="4" valign="top">1</th>
      <th>1</th>
      <th>5</th>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th rowspan="3" valign="top">2</th>
      <th>5</th>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>6</th>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>8</th>
      <td>9</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th rowspan="3" valign="top">2</th>
      <th rowspan="3" valign="top">3</th>
      <th>5</th>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>6</th>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>8</th>
      <td>9</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th rowspan="2" valign="top">3</th>
      <th>1</th>
      <th>8</th>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>2</th>
      <th>7</th>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

        <style  type="text/css" >
        
        
        </style>

        <table id="T_ae86631e_1789_11e6_aa5c_3417ebaea714" None>
        

        <thead>
            
            <tr>
                
                <th class="blank">
                
                <th class="blank">
                
                <th class="blank">
                
                <th class="col_heading level0 col0">Val
                
            </tr>
            
            <tr>
                
                <th class="col_heading level2 col0">A
                
                <th class="col_heading level2 col1">B
                
                <th class="col_heading level2 col2">C
                
                <th class="blank">
                
            </tr>
            
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            
            <tr>
                
                <th id="T_ae86631e_1789_11e6_aa5c_3417ebaea714" class="row_heading level2 row0">
                    1
                
                <th id="T_ae86631e_1789_11e6_aa5c_3417ebaea714" class="row_heading level2 row0">
                    1
                
                <th id="T_ae86631e_1789_11e6_aa5c_3417ebaea714" class="row_heading level2 row0">
                    5
                
                <td id="T_ae86631e_1789_11e6_aa5c_3417ebaea714row0_col0" class="data row0 col0">
                    1
                
            </tr>
            
            <tr>
                
                <th id="T_ae86631e_1789_11e6_aa5c_3417ebaea714" class="row_heading level0 row1">
                    1
                
                <th id="T_ae86631e_1789_11e6_aa5c_3417ebaea714" class="row_heading level0 row1">
                    2
                
                <th id="T_ae86631e_1789_11e6_aa5c_3417ebaea714" class="row_heading level0 row1">
                    5
                
                <td id="T_ae86631e_1789_11e6_aa5c_3417ebaea714row1_col0" class="data row1 col0">
                    4
                
            </tr>
            
            <tr>
                
                <th id="T_ae86631e_1789_11e6_aa5c_3417ebaea714" class="row_heading level0 row2">
                    1
                
                <th id="T_ae86631e_1789_11e6_aa5c_3417ebaea714" class="row_heading level0 row2">
                    2
                
                <th id="T_ae86631e_1789_11e6_aa5c_3417ebaea714" class="row_heading level0 row2">
                    6
                
                <td id="T_ae86631e_1789_11e6_aa5c_3417ebaea714row2_col0" class="data row2 col0">
                    4
                
            </tr>
            
            <tr>
                
                <th id="T_ae86631e_1789_11e6_aa5c_3417ebaea714" class="row_heading level0 row3">
                    1
                
                <th id="T_ae86631e_1789_11e6_aa5c_3417ebaea714" class="row_heading level0 row3">
                    2
                
                <th id="T_ae86631e_1789_11e6_aa5c_3417ebaea714" class="row_heading level0 row3">
                    8
                
                <td id="T_ae86631e_1789_11e6_aa5c_3417ebaea714row3_col0" class="data row3 col0">
                    9
                
            </tr>
            
            <tr>
                
                <th id="T_ae86631e_1789_11e6_aa5c_3417ebaea714" class="row_heading level0 row4">
                    2
                
                <th id="T_ae86631e_1789_11e6_aa5c_3417ebaea714" class="row_heading level0 row4">
                    3
                
                <th id="T_ae86631e_1789_11e6_aa5c_3417ebaea714" class="row_heading level0 row4">
                    5
                
                <td id="T_ae86631e_1789_11e6_aa5c_3417ebaea714row4_col0" class="data row4 col0">
                    2
                
            </tr>
            
            <tr>
                
                <th id="T_ae86631e_1789_11e6_aa5c_3417ebaea714" class="row_heading level0 row5">
                    2
                
                <th id="T_ae86631e_1789_11e6_aa5c_3417ebaea714" class="row_heading level0 row5">
                    3
                
                <th id="T_ae86631e_1789_11e6_aa5c_3417ebaea714" class="row_heading level0 row5">
                    6
                
                <td id="T_ae86631e_1789_11e6_aa5c_3417ebaea714row5_col0" class="data row5 col0">
                    3
                
            </tr>
            
            <tr>
                
                <th id="T_ae86631e_1789_11e6_aa5c_3417ebaea714" class="row_heading level0 row6">
                    2
                
                <th id="T_ae86631e_1789_11e6_aa5c_3417ebaea714" class="row_heading level0 row6">
                    3
                
                <th id="T_ae86631e_1789_11e6_aa5c_3417ebaea714" class="row_heading level0 row6">
                    8
                
                <td id="T_ae86631e_1789_11e6_aa5c_3417ebaea714row6_col0" class="data row6 col0">
                    9
                
            </tr>
            
            <tr>
                
                <th id="T_ae86631e_1789_11e6_aa5c_3417ebaea714" class="row_heading level0 row7">
                    3
                
                <th id="T_ae86631e_1789_11e6_aa5c_3417ebaea714" class="row_heading level0 row7">
                    1
                
                <th id="T_ae86631e_1789_11e6_aa5c_3417ebaea714" class="row_heading level0 row7">
                    8
                
                <td id="T_ae86631e_1789_11e6_aa5c_3417ebaea714row7_col0" class="data row7 col0">
                    4
                
            </tr>
            
            <tr>
                
                <th id="T_ae86631e_1789_11e6_aa5c_3417ebaea714" class="row_heading level0 row8">
                    3
                
                <th id="T_ae86631e_1789_11e6_aa5c_3417ebaea714" class="row_heading level0 row8">
                    2
                
                <th id="T_ae86631e_1789_11e6_aa5c_3417ebaea714" class="row_heading level0 row8">
                    7
                
                <td id="T_ae86631e_1789_11e6_aa5c_3417ebaea714row8_col0" class="data row8 col0">
                    4
                
            </tr>
            
        </tbody>
        </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

if you:

```
from IPython.core.display import HTML
```

then

```
HTML(tbl.to_html())
```

or

```
HTML(tbl.style.render())
```

They certainly do look different.

From the [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/style.html)

> Provisional: This is a new feature and still under development. We'll be adding features and possibly making breaking changes in future releases. We'd love to hear your feedback.

What I've done myself is to attach the `id` and `class` and `style` to the output of `to_html()` to style my tables.

Comment: My bad -- should have been `tbl.to_html()` and `tbl.style.render()` -- they do render quite differently.
I'm trying to put them into an email.

Comment: How exactly do you attach classes to the output of `to_html()`? By manually parsing it?